# Using glass pipe

Tags: aquarium

I want to use glass pipe instead of a regular fitting for bottom drain of my aquarium.

for example 10cm of glass pipe that glued to the bottom hole of aquarium using silicon sealant and the end of it connected to a hose that can go to sump...

am i going to have leakage problem or anything?
anyone ever tried glass pipes in aquariums?

Comment: what type of tank do you have,will the glass in your tank handle the stress from drilling and mounting a drain,why use a glass pipe when you can buy pre fabricated bottom drains made for fish tanks.

Comment: @trondhansen 
i'm making the tank my self with normal glass, normal fittings have at least 2cm height that will prevent the debris from going into the drain. i need the drain and bottom at the same level.

Answer (score 1):

I would follow the routine procedures. A plastic bulkhead fitting, rubber washers, with plastic pipe. That provides a little flexibility. A glass or silicone joint would have almost zero flexibility. And you can change the bulkhead in the future.

Of the many hundreds of aquariums I have seen, I do not remember seeing a glass nor silicone connection. I might mention aquarium bottoms are normally tempered glass and do not drill easily. They are usually purchased with holes.

Comment: i'm making the tank my self with normal glass, normal fittings have at least 2cm height that will prevent the debris from going into the drain. i need the drain and bottom at the same level.